# Trouble with homebrew and libsodium

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew, php-7.4, libsodium

I have a few versions of php on my system(macOS):
7.4, 8.0, 8.1 and 8.2

I need to switch between these regularly for different projects.
I've run into a problem with laravel where when i try to run any valet commands when PHP7.4 is linked, i get the error message:

```
dyld[68591]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
```

It tries several folders and cannot find this version of libsodium, however libsodium.26.dylib exists.
I try to use brew to install libsodium 23 using:

```
brew install libsodium@1.0.23
```

But get this message:

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "libsodium@1.0.23". Did you mean libsodium?
```

edit:
So there is a slight mistake in that I thought the number in the libsodium dylib file corresponded to what version of libsodium was installed (I thought 1.0.26 was installed since the dylib file was called libsodium.26.dylib)

However this cannot be the case as the latest version of libsodium is 1.0.19.

This explains why 'brew install libsodium@1.0.23' doesn't work (as that version doesn't exist yet).

In which case, how do I get valet to look for libsodium.26.dylib, rather than 23 like it is now?

Answer (score 15):

Reinstall libsodium using brew. It should fix the broken php installs.

Run:
`brew reinstall libsodium`

Comment: I had the same issue with ffmpeg and libsodium.26.dylib but I tried reinstalling both libsodium and ffmpeg and it doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

I ended up doing a full `brew upgrade` and something in there did end up fixing it.

Comment: thanks @David Adão, this also worked in my case.
i ran `npx react-native clean` and got this error:
`✖ Delete Watchman cache » Error: Command was killed with SIGABRT (Aborted): watchman watch-del-all`
`dyld[35788]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib`

Comment: I also had an issue with ffmpeg, and `brew reinstall zeromq` fixed my case.

Edit: Reason was that zeromq was referencing version 23 dynamic libs of libsodium, but version 26 had been installed.

Comment: For those wondering, reinstalling libsodium didn't work, however brucek's fix worked for me, must have been something in my homebrew installation.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12):

In my case it happened after running `brew upgrade`. The error I received (after trying to execute `composer install`):

```
dyld[75922]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: <XXX> /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.7_1/bin/php
```

I managed to fix it by reinstalling PHP 8.2:

```
brew reinstall php
```

Comment: `brew reinstall shivammathur/php/php@8.4` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to remove this folder:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.7_1/bin/php
```

My error also said:

```
dyld[85622]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: <####> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.7_1/bin/php
```

After the folder was removed I could run Composer and reinstall properly.

Answer (score -1):

This might work if you are using PhpStorm:
Go to terminal settings and disable "Add default project PHP interpreter to $PATH". Do not forget to open a new terminal.

Comment: Unsure how `PhpStorm` comes into this question?

Comment: I faced the exact same issue when I started using PhpStorm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).